# How to load another post if condition is true

Tags: hooks

if a condition is true I want to display another post selected by its id on single.php.
I have this, that gives me the current id. But how can I load the content (title and acf-fields) of another post. I tried "the_content" but it did not work.

```
function change_post() {
 $post = get_post();
 echo $post->ID;
 //lets say we have id 1
 if($conditon){     
   echo "load post 2" 
 }
}
add_filter( 'wp', 'change_post' );
```

**edit:**

I found this solution:

```
function redirectPost () {
  if(is_single(661)){
   wp_redirect( get_permalink(112) );
   die;
  }
 }

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirectPost' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the desired post ID to [get_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/). So inside your conditional, do the work to determine the post ID you need (`$new_post_id`), then use `$post = get_post( $new_post_id )`.

Comment: thanks! I tried something like: add_filter('the_posts', function(){
    $newPostId = 112;
    return [get_post($newPostId)];

});, but I think it is not working with ACF-Fields.